# ORDER BY FIELD(id, ?) not working in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to execute a query that shows only articles inside this array `$res`. It contains article IDs

```
$res = Array ( [0] => 42 [1] => 41 );

$res1 = $res;
$res2 = $res;

$Search = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE id IN :res1
    ORDER BY FIELD(id, :res2);
");

$Search->execute([
    ':res1' => $res1,
    ':res2' => $res2
]);
```

but it is returnig this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? ORDER BY FIELD(id, ?)' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(16): PDO->prepare('\r\n\t\t\tSELECT * F...')

Comment: `WHERE id IN` expects a list like `('1','2')`, but you gave is a string like `'blah'`. Also Field probably wants an int instead of a string.

Comment: explane more if you can

Comment: @jay-blanchard I don't think this is a dupe. His code doesn't appear to try and replace a table or column name like the question you linked.

Comment: that is the problem @bassxzero my question is not duplicated

Comment: I'm aware it's not a dup., but i didn't close it and I can't open it

Comment: @bwoebi can you reopen this?

Comment: He is not responding. I really hate that

Comment: it was because you duplicate it. I did not say that because you reply lately

Comment: This indeed is not a dupe, but the same issue though

Comment: *"He is not responding. I really hate that "* is what you said. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ayyy @JayBlanchard ty

Comment: lets make that clear. responding => Disable Duplication  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass an array as a parameter. That won't work. Also, `IN` takes a comma separated list inside parentheses, and that's not how to declare an array in PHP.

```
$res = [42, 41];

$params = array_merge($res, $res);
// build a big list of question marks
// for a two element array we get ?,?
$placeholder = trim(str_repeat("?,", count($res)), ",");

$Search = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE id IN ($placeholder)
    ORDER BY FIELD(id, $placeholder);
");

$Search->execute($params);
```

Comment: I got the mistake, so I forgot that by using Order By, I introduced another `?` for params, but I was just using only one in execute! This solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
I know it's missing your order by, but we can get to that in a minute.

```
$res = Array ( '0' => 42 '1' => 41 );

$inQuery = $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($res), '?'));


$Search = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE id IN ({$inQuery})    
");

$Search->execute($res);
```

Comment: are you certain that i don't need FIELD because in my code documentation 
i have `The ORDER BY FIELD clause is important otherwise the database engine will not return the results in required order`